# TFS 2010 Product Backlog permissions

Tags: tfs

I know this is a permissions issue but I can not find the answer on the web.  I am a newbie TFS administrator and after setting up a new Default collection everything for me looks fine.  I set a group that has full control to the site and when the user tries to view the Product Backlog items, Project Work Items, and Recent Checkin’s they all come up with no results.  (the Recent Checkins gives the error "TF10127: The path does not include a source control item. Type or select a different path") This points to a TFS database access issue.  Can someone point me in the right direction for getting the permissions correct for these items to show up for the users?

---

So one thing I noticed and please tell me if this a standard issue.   I used TFS admin to set the permissions for people and that seemed to work fine.  I then set the permissions for an AD group and they could see the stories in the Product Backlog but when they clicked on a user story the popup/editing window would show 403 Forbidden.  If I pulled an AD user out of the AD group and set the same permissions then the user did not have the 403 Forbidden and they were able to see the user story edit page.

Any ideas?

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you download the TFS Admin Tool from Codeplex. This is an open source tool that really simplifies managing permissions for users across TFS, SharePoint and reporting. 
http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/

There is no direct answer to your question. However, i would like to point out this great article on MSDN that gives you a walk through on the preferred approach for setting up permissions and security for users on TFS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252477.aspx .

Comment: I went through and reset the permissions with the TFS Admin Tool and now all is working well.  Thank you for the help